# Dismiss "check your charger" dialog

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently working on an Android app that's gonna be used in a kiosk setup (on a tablet, always running, only this one app, etc etc).

We are using Lenovo tablets, with a connected USB hub for USB devices and also for powering the tablet. Generally, this works fine, but when the power is plugged in, the tablet will show a system dialog saying "check your charger connection" as the tablet thinks something is wrong with the charger (there isn't anything wrong, it charges fine, so I assume it's some kind of issue in the USB handshake).

Now, obviously I should get in contact with Lenovo about this - but in the meam time I was thinking if it might be possible to programatically dismiss this dialog in some way?

Is it possible to "catch" when the dialog opens up and dismiss it from the app in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your codes you have done?

Comment: I highly doubt you can dismiss system dialogs from your own code. By the way, I believe such dialogs show when it detects it isn't able to charge at some specific minimum amount of speed, i.e when the amperage is relatively low. That sometimes happens when you don't use the original charger or cable, or when the cable is damaged, which often just happens by normal wear and tear. In my experience most charger cables reduce in performance because of it, sometimes much faster than expected. I often buy new cables because of it. It can also mean that the charging port of the device simply is dirty

Comment: @Ivo It's a brand new tablet with brand new powered USB hub, so it's not a wear issue. I've tested with different tablets/hubs/chargers so it's not an issue on that front. 
You might be right about it not being possible to dismiss system dialogs, but it was worth a shot if anyone had an idea. Thanks anyway!